# How to bind a Kendo grid without storing the data into database

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a kendo dropdownlist and an Add button and a Kendo grid.

I want to bind the data from the dropdownlist to the kendo grid on clicking the Add button.
Here I do not want to store the data in database and retrieve it. I want to achieve this without storing into the database.

Please can any body let me know how to achieve this???

Thanks 
Deepak

Comment: You don't want to store the data in the DB but you didn't say where it comes from. Is it always the same? Do you know it while are preparing the page or do you want to get it from a static file?

Comment: I think that is what the OP is asking: How else would you do it? one option would be xml files. No database per say, but a structured data source all the same.

Comment: The data finally has to get stored in to the database itself but before doing that I have to bind the grid with kendo dropdownlist data.